# My cordova application not launching after NFC tag detect

Tags: android, cordova, phonegap-plugins, nfc, ndef

I am using `Apache cordova` to build android applications. I made an application with `NFC` feature.

we already written data into NFC tag, with `mimetype: myApp/firstNFCApp`. Inside my application whenever detect tag with this `mimetype` my application will read data and showing that data into user friendly manner. This way I implemented, it's working fine.This was the code I written to fetch data from tag

```
nfc.addNdefListener(
     function(nfcEvent){
       console.log(nfc.bytesToString(nfcEvent.tag.ndefMessage[0].payload));
     },
     function(){
       console.log("sucessfully created");
     },
     function(){
       console.log("something went wrong");
     }
);
```

Now I want to launch my application,whenever device detect a tag with `mimetype: myApp/firstNFCApp` . For this, I written following code

```
<intent-filter>
  <data android:mimeType="myApp/firstNFCApp" />
  <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
</intent-filter>
```

and I added `android:noHistory="true"` to `activity` element in `androidManifest.xml` file.

What I want :

If the device detect any tag with my mimetype,want to launch application also need's to trigger that callback(means,console will print).I am using `chariotsolutions/phonegap-nfc` plugin.

This is way, I tried it's not working. can anyone help me thank you.

Answer (score 1):

In order to receive an NFC intent together with the whole NDEF message in your app, you would need to define a proper intent filter that matches the first record in the above NDEF message:

```
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.nfc.action.NDEF_DISCOVERED" />
    <action android:name="android.nfc.action.TAG_DISCOVERED" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
</intent-filter>
```

[Refer how to handle NFC](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/nfc/nfc.html)

Answer (score 0):

As SweetWisher wrote, you need to define a proper action for your intent filter (`android.nfc.action.NDEF_DISCOVERED`( in your case. In addition, you should be aware that MIME types used in the `NDEF_DISCOVERED` intent filter must always be all-lower-case. The reason is that MIME types are case-insensitive as per the RFC but Android's intent filter matching is case-sensitive. Consequently, Android will convert MIME types to all-lower-case before matching in order to overcome case-sensitivity issues (see [this answer for a more detailed explaination](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22096761/2425802)).

As a result, you intent filter would look something like this:

```
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.nfc.action.NDEF_DISCOVERED" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    <data android:mimeType="myapp/firstnfcapp" />
</intent-filter>
```