# Read NFC tag has content of Android Play app

Tags: android, android-intent, nfc

I have a tag has content of Android Play app. When phone approach it, it'll default open the app  page on Android Play Store.
Now I want to do is to write an app can read this Tag. So I modify AndroidManifest.xml as below:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.NFC" />
......
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>

        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.nfc.action.NDEF_DISCOVERED" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <data
                android:host="ext"
                android:pathPrefix="/android.com:pkg"
                android:scheme="vnd.android.nfc" />
        </intent-filter>
......
```

I use another Tag App to read this Tag, it has content like:

```
NDEF message
EXTERNAL: urn:nfc:ext:android.com:pkg
com.example.app
```

I think the key point is the intent-filter. But I cannot lunch my App when approach this tag. No matter my App is in background or foreground. Does anyone can help me? Thanks.

Comment: [Check this if it helps](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26698189/2591002) And if you have other app which is also registered for the same Action, you will be given dialogue to choose the app you want to open.

Comment: There is no dialogue to choose the app while there is no app in foreground. And I think if several app registered for same Action, the foreground app will be the default lunched.

Comment: but if no app in foreground, then also it opens the app (if there is only one) or shows dialogue.. did you check that link?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just find the answer. I misunderstand the meaning of foreground from let this APP being running at foreground. It has to add enableForegroundDispatch as below:

```
private NfcAdapter nfcAdapter;
private PendingIntent mPendingIntent;
private IntentFilter[] mFilters;
private String[][] mTechLists;

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    nfcAdapter = NfcAdapter.getDefaultAdapter(this);
    mPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, new Intent(this, getClass()).addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP), 0);
    IntentFilter ndefPkg = new IntentFilter(NfcAdapter.ACTION_NDEF_DISCOVERED);
    try {
        ndefPkg.addDataScheme("vnd.android.nfc");
        ndefPkg.addDataAuthority("ext", null);
        ndefPkg.addDataPath("/android.com:pkg", 0);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    mFilters = new IntentFilter[] {ndefPkg;
    mTechLists = new String[][] { new String[] { NfcF.class.getName() } };
}

protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    nfcAdapter.enableForegroundDispatch(this, mPendingIntent, mFilters, mTechLists);
}

protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    nfcAdapter.disableForegroundDispatch(this);
}
```